# Columns being recognized in some formulas but not others in R

Tags: r

I am doing survival analysis on a data set in R and building a cox regression model. I want to run a pairwise test function in survminer. When I run the function it does not recognize the columns from the dataset and returns an error:

```
> pairwise_survdiff(
+   formula = Surv(`Days in Treatment - Interuptions`, Outcome == "Cured") ~ 
+     `Reoccuring Case` + 
+     `Number of Times previously Cured` + 
+     `Number of Times Previously Defaulted` + 
+     `IYCF Counselling Received` + 
+     `Medication Teaching Completed` + 
+     `Estimated Days of missed treatment`,
+   data = OTPData_V6,
+   p.adjust.method = "bonferroni", 
+   na.action = na.omit
+ )
Error in `vectbl_as_col_location()`:
! Can't subset columns that don't exist.
✖ Columns `\`Reoccuring Case\``, `\`Number of Times previously Cured\``, `\`Number of Times Previously Defaulted\``, `\`IYCF Counselling Received\``, `\`Medication Teaching Completed\``, etc. don't exist.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

I have checked for the existence of the columns, missing data points in the columns and the formatting of the columns. The columns are all recognized in the rest of the code as I use the same data set in other functions such as coxph() and survfit().

There was a similar problem elsewhere in the code where, seemingly at random, a column such as `Reoccuring Case` would not be recognized but, when you duplicate the argument data=OTPData_V6 with OTPData_V6$`Reoccuring Case` it seems to recognize the columns. I tried that with all the unrecognized columns in this pairwise function and it does not seem to work here as it did elsewhere.

```
> # Why wont this work - it keeps saying the columns don't exist. 
> pairwise_survdiff(formula=Surv(`Days in Treatment - Interuptions`,Outcome=="Cured")~ 
+                     OTPData_V6$`Reoccuring Case`+ 
+                     OTPData_V6$`Number of Times previously Cured`+ OTPData_V6$`Number of Times Previously Defaulted`+ 
+                     OTPData_V6$`IYCF Counselling Received`+ OTPData_V6$`Medication Teaching Completed`
+                   + OTPData_V6$`Estimated Days of missed treatment`,
+                   data=OTPData_V6, p.adjust.method = "bonferroni",na.action = na.omit)
Error in `vectbl_as_col_location()`:
! Can't subset columns that don't exist.
✖ Columns `OTPData_V6$\`Reoccuring Case\``, `OTPData_V6$\`Number of Times previously Cured\``, `OTPData_V6$\`Number of Times Previously Defaulted\``, `OTPData_V6$\`IYCF Counselling Received\``, `OTPData_V6$\`Medication Teaching Completed\``, etc. don't exist.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Using the dput function the data set can be examined:

```
> dput(head(OTPData_V6, 2))
structure(list(`OTP Registration Number` = c(70, 65), `MTI Unique Patient ID` = c(70, 
65), Address = c("Medebay Zana", "Setit Humera"), Nationality = c("Ethiopia", 
"Ethiopia"), Region = c("Tigray", "Tigray"), Zone = c("Northwestern Zone", 
"Western Tigray"), Woreda = c("Medebay Zana", "Kafta Humera"), 
    `Age at first Admission (Months)` = c(18, 9), `Age at Discharge` = c(23, 
    13), `Age recorded at OTP Registration (Months)` = c(18, 
    9), Sex = structure(c(1L, 1L), levels = c("Female", "Male"
    ), class = "factor"), `Reoccuring Case` = structure(c(1L, 
    1L), levels = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor"), `New Admission` = structure(c(1L, 
    1L), levels = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor"), `Transfer or Readmission` = structure(c(2L, 
    2L), levels = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor"), `Number of Times Previously Admitted to OTP` = c(0, 
    0), `Number of Times previously Cured` = c(0, 0), `Number of Times Previously Defaulted` = c(0, 
    0), `Admission Weight (KG)` = c(5, 6.1), `Admission MUAC` = c(9.4, 
    10.2), `Discharge Date` = c("11/5/2021", "11/5/2021"), `Length of Treatment Period (Days)` = c(154, 
    135), `Days in Treatment - Interuptions` = c(140, 121), `Total Time Elapsed from First OTP Admission` = c(154, 
    135), `Total Days in Treatment since first admission` = c(140, 
    121), `Discharge Weight (KG)` = c(NA_real_, NA_real_), `Discharge MUAC` = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_), Outcome = structure(c(3L, 3L), levels = c("Cured", 
    "Default", "Default due to stockout", "Ongoing"), class = "factor"), 
    `Number of Technical Defaults during treatment period` = c(1, 
    1), `Number of stockout periods during treatment` = c(2, 
    2), `Estimated Days of missed treatment` = c(14, 14), `Number of stockout periods during treatment - Warehouse` = c(2, 
    2), `Estimated Days of missed treatment - Warehouse` = c(14, 
    14), Displaced = structure(c(2L, 2L), levels = c("Host", 
    "Yes"), class = "factor"), `First OTP Registration Date` = c("6/4/2021", 
    "6/23/2021"), `OTP registration date` = c("6/4/2021", "6/23/2021"
    ), `Arrival Date` = c("6/4/2021", "6/23/2021"), NCD = structure(c(1L, 
    1L), levels = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor"), `Communicable (Infectious) Dx` = structure(c(1L, 
    1L), levels = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor"), Trauma = c(0, 
    0), `Acute Bloody Diarrhea` = structure(c(1L, 1L), levels = c("No", 
    "Yes"), class = "factor"), `Acute Respiratory Infection` = structure(c(1L, 
    1L), levels = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor"), `Acute Watery Diarrhea` = structure(c(1L, 
    1L), levels = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor"), `Diarrhea Unspecified` = structure(c(1L, 
    1L), levels = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor"), Dysentery = c(0, 
    0), `Fever or unknown origin` = c(0, 0), Pneumonia = structure(c(1L, 
    1L), levels = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor"), Scabies = structure(c(1L, 
    1L), levels = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor"), `Suspected Cholera` = c(0, 
    0), `Suspected Covid-19` = c(0, 0), `Suspected Hepatitis` = c(0, 
    0), `Suspected HIV` = c(0, 0), `Suspected Intestinal Parasite` = structure(c(1L, 
    1L), levels = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor"), `Suspected Malaria` = c(0, 
    0), `Suspected Measles` = c(0, 0), `Suspected Meningitis` = c(0, 
    0), `Suspected TB` = c(0, 0), `Skin Infection` = structure(c(1L, 
    1L), levels = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor"), `Typhoid Fever` = c(0, 
    0), `Urinary Tract Infection` = c(0, 0), Conjunctivitis = structure(c(1L, 
    1L), levels = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor"), `IYCF Counselling Received` = structure(c(1L, 
    1L), levels = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor"), `Prescriptions Filled: Yes` = structure(c(1L, 
    1L), levels = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor"), `Prescriptions Filled: No` = structure(c(1L, 
    1L), levels = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor"), `Medication Teaching Completed` = structure(c(1L, 
    1L), levels = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor"), `Referral Made` = c(0, 
    0)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Comment: Can you share your data using `dput(OTPData_V6)` please? It's difficult to diagnose the problem without this.

Comment: Thanks, I think the formatting is a little unclear since I posted it. `Days in Treatment - Interuptions` is a single variable/column for the time to event or survival time in the data set.  I have tried to run the function with the backticks, `Reoccuring Case` as well as with and without the duplicated operator OTPData_V6$.

Comment: The data set is rather large to share with dput(OTPData_V6).

Comment: I strongly suggest that you rename the columns to syntactically valid names. (And never use `$` within a formula. Intsead rely on the `data` parameter).

Comment: If the data set is too large, then could you share `dput(head(OTPData_V6, 10))`?

Comment: I get the same sort of errors when running the 'stepwiseCox()' function but not the 'step()' function. The columns are recognized as correctly formatted factors in one but not the other.

Comment: Do different libraries sometimes read columns differently? More and more I see the columns in the data set being recognized in some formulas and errors that the columns don't exist in others. The labels are copied from one formula to the next so, I don't think it is just a syntax error.